# How to declare static C++ function as friend on OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, visual-c++, glfw

I've built an application twice: once in Visual Studio and another time in XCode. One of the libraries I used, GLFW, allows you to use the `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback` function to detect resizing of the window.

My window class, `Window`, has two private members, width and height. And upon the calling of my callback, `window_size_callback`, I wanted the values of width and height to be updated. However, I wanted to do this without the use of setters.

So, I made `window_size_callback` a static friend. This solution worked just fine in the Visual Studio compiler; however, XCode returned an error: 'static' is invalid in friend declarations.

`window_size_callback`:

```
void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    Window* win = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    win->width = width;
    win->height = height;
}
```

`glfwGetWindowUserPointer` is used to get the current window instance from outside of the class.

header file:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Window {
private:
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
private:
    friend static void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
}
```

Without the friend keyword, `window_size_callback` is unable to access these members.

Why is VS fine with this and XCode not?

And, how can I get around this without using setters?

Comment: What's the point of a static friend? Friend functions aren't a part of the class anyway... Also a code segment is worth a thousand words.

Comment: It needs to be a friend in order to modify the private members of my class when the window is resized @DeiDei

Comment: Then make it friend, but why does it need to be static?

Comment: It's a callback @DeiDei

Comment: I just don't understand your problem, probably because you haven't posted any code. That would greatly help. Static functions have all the access to the class members just like friend functions do, but static functions are member functions while friends are free functions.

Comment: I've added code @DeiDei

Comment: Since GLFW expects C callbacks, you need to ensure C calling conventions. You can forward declare it as: `extern "C" { static void fn (...); }`, and then implement: `static void fn (...) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `static`. It makes no sense as I explained in the comments. Here's a snippet that should clear things:

```
class Window {
private:
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
private:
    friend void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int);
};

// as you can see 'window_size_callback' is implemented as a free function
// not as a member function which is what 'static' implies
void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    Window* win = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    win->width = width;
    win->height = height;
}
```

A `friend` function cannot be a `static` member of a class. I'm guessing VS allows the syntax as an extension. Don't count on it.